# Cual es la diferencia entre el uso de parentesis y el dunder __call__ en Python?

Tags: python

Tengo este codigo de ejemplo:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(metaclass, cls_name, bases, attrs):
        print(f'Saludos desde el dunder __new__ de la clase Meta')
        return type(cls_name, bases, attrs)




class Persona(metaclass = Meta):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __call__():
        print(f'Saludos desde el dunder __call__ de la clase Persona')

print(Persona())
```

Pues bien (en python3) al ejecutar este codigo de imprime por pantalla ...

```
Saludos desde el dunder __new__ de la clase Meta
<__main__.Persona object at 0x7fc3a8a27910>
```

Sin embargo en caso de que se sustituya los `()` por `.__call__()`, deja de funcionar como se esperaria ....

**codigo**

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(metaclass, cls_name, bases, attrs):
        print(f'Saludos desde el dunder __new__ de la clase Meta')
        return type(cls_name, bases, attrs)




class Persona(metaclass = Meta):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __call__():
        print(f'Saludos desde el dunder __call__ de la clase Persona')

print(Persona.__call__())
```

**salida**

```
Saludos desde el dunder __new__ de la clase Meta
Saludos desde el dunder __call__ de la clase Persona
None
```

Es interesante ya que se supone que ambos ejemplos son equivalentes, sin embargo, en el segundo ejemplo vemos que accede al atributo `__call__` de `Persona` algo que podria ser intuitivo, sin embargo no pasa en el primer ejemplo. Con lo cual, la pregunta seria: a cual `__call__` se accede en el primer ejemplo?, y ademas, no se supone que ambos ejemplos son equivalentes?

**Aclaratoria**

Algo que me llamo aun mas la atencion de este ejemplo, es que en el primer caso (cuando se emplea `()`) se podria pensar que se accede al dunder `__call__` de la metaclase (cual el caso en el que estemos instanciando), pero no ...

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(metaclass, cls_name, bases, attrs):
        print(f'Saludos desde el dunder __new__ de la clase Meta')
        return type(cls_name, bases, attrs)
    def __call__(*args):
        print(f'Saludos desde el dunder __call__ de la clase Meta')




class Persona(metaclass = Meta):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __call__():
        print(f'Saludos desde el dunder __call__ de la clase Persona')

print(Persona())
```

**salida**

```
Saludos desde el dunder __new__ de la clase Meta
<__main__.Persona object at 0x7f8f3ce6a7f0>
```

Comment: Tu código contiene errores de sintaxis (falta el parámetro `self` en el método `__call___`. Corrigelos y prueba de nuevo. También tienes una confusión entre clases e instancias a la hora de aplicar los métodos.

Comment: No le agrege el self al __call__ de Persona precisamente para poder llamarlo con la clase

Comment: Ambas llamadas NO son equivalentes. Con `Persona()` estás creando una instancia, mientras con `Persona.__call__()` estás invocando directamente un método de la clase, sin instancia creada. Haz más pruebas, como hacer varias llamadas a `Persona.__call__()` y a `Persona()`, añade lo que has probado e intentamos razonar sobre lo que pasa.

Comment: Pues no es lo mismo `__call__` es un método de una clase y el usar los paréntesis `()` es otra cosa  esto le indica a python que un objeto callable y hará todo el proceso de crear la instancia de la clase

Answer (score 1):

La sintaxis `algo(parametros)` se traduce en Python en diferentes acciones, según cuál sea el tipo de `algo`. En la mayoría de los casos se acaba convirtiendo en `algo.__call__()`, **excepto** si `algo` es una clase. Estos son los detalles:

- Si `algo` es una función, se invoca la función pasándole los parámetros. Ya que las funciones son en realidad *instancias* del tipo `function`, son objetos e implementan un metodo `__call__()`, por lo que la llamada a la función sería equivalente a `Algo.__call__(parametros)`
- Si `algo` es una función generadora (una que contenga `yield`), la llamada se resuelve como si fuera una función "normal", solo que el resultado no es la ejecución de esa función, sino la creación de un objeto iterador, sobre el que luego se puede iterar.
- Si es una corutina asíncrona (una que lleva `async` delante del `def`) también se resuelve de la misma forma, pero el resultado no es la ejecución de la función, sino la creación de un objeto de tipo `coroutine`, que debe ser ejecutado después por un bucle de eventos como el de `asyncio`
- Si es un generador asíncrono (una función que lleve `async` delante, y que contenga `yield`) también se resuelve de la misma forma, pero el resultado no es la ejecución de la rutina, sino la creación de un objeto de tipo `async_generator`, sobre el que se podrá iterar después usando `async for` (cosa que solo puede hacerse desde una corutina que esté siendo ejecutada por un bucle de eventos).
- Si `algo` es un método de un objeto (la sintaxis sería en realidad `objeto.algo(parametros)` en este caso), la cosa es bastante más compleja, y no está relacionada directamente con la pregunta, por lo que no entraré en mucho detalle, pero digamos que al final la llamada acaba convirtiéndose también en una llamada a una función, siendo esa función un atributo del objeto, pero antes de ello Python debe determinar si se trata de un método estático, un método de clase o un método "normal", pues si es un método estático no añade nada a los parámetros, si es un método de clase añade una referencia a la clase como primer parámetro, y si es un método normal añade una referencia al propio objeto como primer parámetro. Por tanto la llamada acaba siendo equivalente a una de estas tres (siendo `cls` la clase de la cual `objeto` es instancia):

  - `cls.algo.__call__(parametros)` (si el método era estático, es decir, estaba decorado con `@staticmethod`)
  - `cls.algo.__call__(cls, parametros)` (si el método era de clase, es decir, estaba decorado con `@classmethod`)
  - `cls.algo.__call__(objeto, parametros)` (si el método era "normal"
- Si `algo` es una *instancia*  de una clase `cls`, entonces `algo(parámetros)` causa que se invoque `cls.__call__` (insertando delante de los parámetros el objeto  `algo`, a menos que `cls.__call__` hubiera sido decorado con `@staticmethod`, en cuyo caso no se insertaría, o con `@classmethod` en cuyo caso se insertaría `cls` como primer parámetro, igual que se explicó antes para los métodos de objeto).
- Finalmente, si `algo` es una clase, entonces `algo()` se resuelve como `algo.__new__(algo)` y no como `algo.__call__()`.

Por tanto este último caso es el que está directamente relacionado con tu pregunta, y el que te está causando confusión.

Una vez aclarado esto, podemos plantear un ejemplo que te ayude a comprender qué está pasando. Lo primero, en ese ejemplo no son necesarias metaclases, y si las quitamos de enmedio el problema puede ser más fácil de entender.

```
class Persona():
    def __new__(cls):
      print(f"Saludos desde el dunder __new__ de la clase Persona, con cls={cls}")
      return super().__new__(cls)
    def __init__(self):
        print(f'Saludos desd el dunder __init__ de la clase Persona, con self={self}')
    @staticmethod
    def __call__():
        print(f'Saludos desde el dunder __call__ de la clase Persona')
```

Ahora pensemos qué hace cada una de las siguientes invocaciones:

#### `p = Persona()`

Según lo antes dicho, eso se convierte en `Persona.__new__(Persona)`. La misión de `new()` es devolver una instancia de esa clase (en casos raros podría devolver una instancia de otra clase diferente). Normalmente no es necesario implementar `__new__()` porque todas las clases Python heredan de la clase `object`, la cual ya implementa un `__new__()` que por defecto hace lo que acabo de describir: crear y retornar un objeto de la clase `Persona` en este caso.

Sobre el objeto retornado seguidamente se invoca `__init__()`, por lo que se hace en realidad al final es algo como:

```
obj_anonimo = Persona.__new__(Persona)
Persona.__init__(obj_anonimo)
p = obj_anonimo
```

Como ves, en ningún momento se ha usado `__call__()`. Al implementar `Persona.__call__()` lo que consigues es que el propio objeto `p` que acabamos de crear sea *callable*. Es decir, que podemos hacer:

#### `p()`

Y tal como se explicó antes, eso se traduce en una llamada a `Persona.__call__()`. Y ya que en este caso hemos añadido a `__call__` el atributo `@staticmethod` eso hará que Python no inserte `p` como primer parámetro de esa función (por lo que no fue necesario declarar `self` en la misma).

#### Demo

```py
>>> p = Persona()
Saludos desde el dunder __new__ de la clase Persona, con cls=<class '__main__.Persona'>
Saludos desd el dunder __init__ de la clase Persona, con self=<__main__.Persona object at 0x7f31781b2a90>

>>> p
<__main__.Persona at 0x7f31781b2a90>

>>> p()
Saludos desde el dunder __call__ de la clase Persona

>>> p.__call__()
Saludos desde el dunder __call__ de la clase Persona
```

Y observa que en este ejemplo particular, por ser un staticmethod, podríamos también hacer `Persona.__call__()` para llegar al mismo resultado. Lo normal es que `__call__()` no sea estático, para así recibir un parámetro `self` que le permita acceder a los atributos del objeto.